# No touch event on resized UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

My problem is after increasing the height of UIView from 40pt (height mentioned in storyboard) to size around (1400) after updating data inside its UITableView child. The view is not getting events in increased area. It only receives touch event below original height.

View Heirarchy in xib file

```
ScrolView      
  - UIView(1) 
    -- UIView (1.1)  
    -- UIView (1.2)  (commentView) (width superview.width, height - 40) 
       ---UITableView (1.2.1) (commentTableView) (not in xib)
```

My code is -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    commentView = view.viewWithTag(999)
    // adding tableview inside comment view
    if commentView != nil {
        commentTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, commentView.frame.width, commentView.frame.height))
        commentView!.addSubview(commentController!)
    }
}

// After adding rows to table, update size of table 

func afterSettingTableContent() {
     log.info("bound before change\(commentView?.bounds)")
    commentView?.frame.size.height = (commentTableView?.contentSize.height)!

    commentTableView.frame.size.height = (commentView?.frame.height)!
    scrollView.contentSize.height += (commentView?.frame.size.height)!
}
```

Comment: Some possibilities: (1) this work isn't being done on the main thread so it's not updating properly, or (2) some superview is intercepting the touches. Try checking if `NSThread.isMainThread()` is `true`, and setting all views' `clipsToBounds` to `true`.

Comment: data visibility and scrolling is fine. No problem except of touches

Comment: Im assuming you added a tap gesture recognizer to the UIView. Can you post the code where you added the gesture and where you handled it?

Comment: @ahmedOnawale No, there is no extra gesture, only defaults one. Tableview cell contains UIButtons only some portion of first row in able to get event (only first row is able to highlight)

Comment: @VivekBansal Did you try what I suggested with `clipsToBounds`?

Comment: @AaronBrager sry for bothering find out d problem, I m not changing the size UIView (1) i.e superview of comment view. Thanks for help.

Comment: Checkout this answer on SO about how re-sizing UIViews can show sub-views but still have hit-test fail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980670/user-action-in-uiviews-buttons-disabled-after-frame-resizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is height of superview of commentView i.e UIView(1) is fixed. Since clipToBounds is false child views are rendering fine and they are not receiving any touch because their size is still 40. After increasing height of view 1 everything is working fine.(Silly Mistake)